# laravel file uploading in artisan command line

Tags: laravel

I'm writing a Artisan command to do batch image uploads to the application.

Trying to look for the equivalent command to do the following

```
$file = Input::file('photo');
```

Becaues I'm in the command line the Input class doesn't work.

I tried `File::get('/path/to/file')` but it didn't return the same object.

Comment: This is how you get the an uploaded file, but how are you doing the upload?

Comment: From the command line.  I have the path of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Input::file()` will only receive files via form POST:

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="index.php">
  <input type=file name=upload>
  <input type=submit name=press value="OK">
</form>
```

What means that you cannot use `Input::file()` unless you are doing something like this to test your upload

```
curl --form upload=/path/to/file http://your/site/url/upload
```

If you are trying to send files via command, like

```
php artisan upload /path/to/file
```

You'll need to get this filename, read the file from disk and do whatever you need to do with it.